# How to fix an error occupy java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, gradle, import

I'm working on eclipse about Java project. I have a file which I need to import my java gradle project. However, when I build a model for it I get an error which looks like:

`No enum const class java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES`

So, The console says:

`A problem occurred evaluating root project 'mcp_core_root'.`

`> Unable to parse provided TimeUnit: minutes`

The error occupy on that line of file:

`configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 1, 'minutes' }`

I've been working on this problem since two weeks ago.

So, Is there any way to fix it this problem?

Comment: I don't suppose you are trying to use a version prior java 1.6 ...

Comment: First of all thank you for anser, If you mean jdk, it is jdk_1.6.0_105 @AxelH

Comment: Well, this might be the reason if you are compiling for a version 1.5 because [`TimeUnit.MINUTES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#MINUTES) as been introduced in the version 1.6, this could explain the fact that no enum are found for this. You could use `seconds` instead.

Comment: When I used `seconds` instead of `minutes`, I get this error. `Could not find method forkOptions() for arguments [codeAnalysis_2c90eeqf9jc6i6p21qnpotftas$_run_closure1_closure4@71142e50] on root project 'mcp_core_root'.`